# Create global break-point in Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How do I create a Global Conditional  Break-point with the Chrome debugger?

e.g., Break when `location.href` changes.

I see how to create a Conditional break-point on a particular line, but I want to see when the variable is changing.